# How to get corresponding value in two data frame

Tags: r

I have one file:

**File_A:**

```
ID  C1.x    C2.x    C3.x    C4.x    C5.x
M1  60  32  19  25  5
M2  5   14  12  15  5
M3  51  2   2   8   8
M4  15  8   8   8   7
M5  12  86  7   8   9
```

**File_B:**

```
ID  C1.y    C2.y    C3.y    C4.y    C5.y
M1  N   K   K   K   N
M2  M   M   M   M   M
M3  Y   T   T   T   T
M4  A   A   A   A   A
M5  C   C   N   C   C
```

Filter is 5. if less than 5, then corresponding columns should become N.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  Did you meant `df2[-1][df1[-1] <5] <- 'N'`?

Comment: Who upvoted this?  It is not useful, unclear, and shows no research effort.  Come on.

Answer (score 1):

If everything lines up properly, you can simply use:

```
#Test data
dat <- data.frame("ID"=c("M1","M2", "M3", "M4", "M5"), "C1.x"=c(60,5,51,15,12), "C2.x"=c(32,14,2,8,86), "C3.x"=c(19,12,2,8,7), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat2 <- data.frame("ID"=c("M1","M2", "M3", "M4", "M5"), "C1.x"=c("N", "M", "Y", "A", "C"), "C2.x"=c("N", "M", "Y", "A", "C"), "C3.x"=c("N", "M", "Y", "A", "C"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dat2[dat < 5] <- "N"
```

I think that's the output you are looking for. If not, please clarify.